# Selenium Java Webdriver: Asserting double quotes

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

A website displays the following text I need to assert:

```
Living Place "123" hasn't been found
```

I have a piece of ghurkin/cucumber on a webpage I need to assert.assertTrue using Selenum Webdriver Java:

```
The text "Living Place "123" hasn't been found" is present on the page
```

The java Code I've written for this, is as follows:

```
    @Then("^The Text \"([^\"]*)\" isnt present on the page$")   
    public void not_present(String text) throws Throwable {

    waitForTextInElementVisible(By.id("main-content"), text);
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("main-content")).getText().contains(text));
}
```

The problem is, the Gherkin script can't handle the String this way, as it contains a double quote. Is there a way to assert the exact string as given above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, instead of using 
     \"([^\"]*)\",

I had to use \"(.*)\"

this will make the gherkin script work:

And The text "Living Place "123" hasn't been found" is present on the page

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your problem fully.

But you can pass the string as "Living Place \"123\" hasn't been found".
[Note \ before " inside string]

You can call like follows.
not_present("Living Place \"123\" hasn't been found");

Answer (score 0):

try this one `@Then("^The Text \"([^\"]*)\"\d+\"([^\"]*)\" isnt present on the page$")`. This step mapping will be mapped to string in feature file `Then The Text "Living Place "123" hasn't been found" isnt present on the page`. This substitutes the text before digits \"([^\"]*)\" i.e. 'Living Place ', this searches more then one digit symbol in quotation marks \"\d+\" i.e 123, and again part to match text.

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little more?

Comment: I think I know what you are saying, but it doesn't quite work... \"([^\"]*)\" is the standard string we use here, but it needs changing, but I don't know in what